# How can we manually manipulate score field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working on a current scenario where there is a need to boost few documents in case if there is a particular text search.
The scenario is, I have a set of documents where I have to do the term query based on a particular keyword , but the catch here is. Let's say we search for a keyword test it will fetch 100 records but the requirement says that few docs should always come as top result, irrespective of there weightage and other criteria. How can we achieve this is Elasticsearch, any suggestion and ideas are most welcome.

Comment: If you know which documents to boost at index time, you could use a field to mark them and then include that field in the search query. An alternative, if you have some identifiers at search time, then include that in the query.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of what you have and what results you are expecting?

Comment: @jay Let's say when we do term query with "test" keyword, it returns 1000 doc. Lets say we have 4 docs whose id are 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively. So what   I want is every time I do term query with test keyword , these 4 doc should appear in top result as top 4 content. Hope I cleared your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can control relevance with scripts. Take a look at:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html

This is an example using Groovy:

```
price  = doc['price'].value 
margin = doc['margin'].value 

if (price < threshold) { 
  return price * margin / target
}
return price * (1 - discount) * margin / target
```

So, in pseudo-code it would be something like:

```
if (word == 'test') { 
  return score * n
}
return score
```